# Change region after adding new pins

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

When I load my mapView I have only one tick - user location. After some actions I'm adding more pins. But focus is still in user location. I want to magnify the image in order to see all targets. How can I do this?
My code:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    if (views.count == 1) {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
        id<MKAnnotation>mp = [annotationView annotation];
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 500, 500);
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
    } else {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<views.count; i++) {
            [mapView addAnnotation:[views objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MkCoordinateRegion has a member called span. In order to zoom in/out , you have to play with that value:

```
region.span.longitudeDelta = aValue;
region.span.latitudeDelta = aValue;
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: you mean try to create new region in `else` branch?

Comment: Yes , well, you are adding more than 1 annotations there and you want to see them all, right ? That's what I understood from your question. If that is right , you have to compute the maximum distance between them in order to detect the rectangle in which they would all fit. And set that as your new region. I can't see another way of doing it. While computing the distance between some points is not a big deal , I don't know how you would link that to the region span in order to get the zoom level. But I'm sure that there has to be a link between the two.